# Exclude sub-folders from Finder search

Tags: finder, spotlight, search

How can I force Finder to only search the current folder, ignoring the contents of all the sub-folders?
I don't want to exclude the sub-folders permanently from Spotlight, just for a certain search.

The reason I want to do this is that I sometimes have a folder with sub-folders that contain files/folders that are identically named. A simplified example is shown below:

```
main
|
|-config.txt
|
|-folder 1
|  |
|  |-config.txt
|
|-folder 2
   |
   |-config.txt
```

When I'm in `main` and hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type `config.txt` I get three files. I don't want to click every file to see which one is in `main` and which in another folder, so ideally the sub-folders wouldn't show up in this search.

Comment: Interesting question, wonder why !

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing.  Cmd-option-f gives access to some more search options but excluding subfolders doesn't seem available.

Comment: Very surprised that all the answers here involve using something other than Finder. Is there *really* no way to do this from within Finder?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Unix find as follows

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name config.txt -print
```

In Terminal, type `man find` for details.

If you do this often, you can make it into a shell function.

Comment: This was far easier than messing around with the Finder

Answer (score 3):

1. There is a product called [Path Finder 6](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) that offers a feature called "filters and selections," demonstrated [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvZ99gx4E10)
2. You could try selecting all the items in the folder you are searching and applying a Label, then perform a Spotlight search for your item "AND" the additional criteria of "file label" by holding down the option key while clicking on the plus sign.

Comment: Point number 2 is actually the answer. Too bad we need to dance around and there's no way to simply check a box for this. Would actually make a search very simple (not deep/recursive).

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround, although this doesn't *really* answer the question.  Not sure if there's a built-in option for this.

1. In list view, make sure all folders are collapsed --cmd-a (select all) and command-left-arrow are shortcuts for this.
2. *Without* selecting the search box or using cmd-f, begin typing the name of the file "config.txt" and this will select that file in your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I´m thinking that if you tag a colour in all folders in a particular location, you can in the search bar type the name of the folder that you are searching and type the colour you tagged, and finder look for only this label colour. So your finder results in not showing subfolders.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do I understand correctly that if I have 20 subfolder, I would need to go to each folder, select all files and tag with a color? That sounds like a lot of work to find the file in the top folder...

Comment: Hi Neil. You should tag only the top folder (I suppose this is the folder that contains the file you are looking for). On this way Finder only looks for this folder. If you have many subfolders in a particular location (this is simple if this folders are on the same location) you can tag this folders too (that will include this folders in the searching)